# How can i make my angular component to be 100 width of the parent on the root level?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html structure

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-31tboc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftesting-one%2Ftesting-one.component.html

As you can see, here i have component called `app-testing-one` where i am rendering some data.

If i put my component inside `col-7` column width then it will get that width, if i put inside `col-3` then it will be smaller.

But in my case where it is col-3` i need to render my component to have full width of the root parent.

So below `i want this below to be fuyll width` i need to render my component with 100% width.

But i nneed to do this automatically without adding it in col-12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the child component's `display: block` then set the `width: 100%`

eg:

```
:host {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why i need display: block when it works only with width: 100% ?

Comment: By default, components are inline so without a block, flex, or grid, the width won't take effect.

Comment: But if i change only width:100% then it works in my case